# An open file seems to be locked and cannot be uploaded in Microsoft Edge

Tags: file-upload, microsoft-edge

**Steps to Reproduce:**

1. Open file for viewing (i.e. open .xls file in Microsoft Excel)
2. Attempt to upload file in Microsoft Edge browser. Observe file is not uploaded. FYI, I am using the upload file control from a web application. But I don't think this problem is specific to the web application as I can't replicate this issue using Chrome.
3. Close .xls file in Microsoft Excel
4. Attempt to re-upload file and observe it is successful

How would I resolve this, (i.e. have the ability to upload an opened file in Microsoft Edge)? Again, this problem cannot be reproduced using Chrome.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same issue - apparently a Microsoft edge/office bug.

also present with word docs

Only workaround I have found so far is to advise the user to close the file...

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/4675660/
https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/8732443/

Microsoft can be quoted as "hoping to fix it in one of the next releases." (comment is dated Sep 29, 2016 )

I would be keen to hear any other suggested "Workarounds"

Comment: Here is another reference: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-networking-winpc/windows-10-edge-cannot-upload-files-onto-websites/b5ce5ca4-214b-448c-83d1-0c8e72501358